# problems when including a header file

Tags: c++, header

So i'm having a problem when i try to include a header file. I am defining a header and including it in all of my files but i'm getting this error "unresolved external symbol "void_cdecl print(void)"(?print@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main.

my main file TEST.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header1.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

i've only made a simple print function which i define here in Source1.cpp

```
#include "Header1.h"

void print() {
    cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;
}
```

and my header file looks like this - Header1.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

void print();
#endif
```

I did some research i found that this problem is often caused by spelling mistakes but i really cant see it.

Comment: You sure that name of you header file is "Header1.h" and not "Header1.cpp"?  As you said it in description

Comment: yeah, its .h i've changed it now.

Comment: The error is caused because you didn't link the compiled `Source1.cpp` file.

Comment: Is the `Source1.cpp` file actually in the project? You don't get any errors compiling `Source1.cpp` (like failing to include `"stdafx.h"`)?

Comment: Yeah, the cpp is in the projekt. "    
The error is caused because you didn't link the compiled Source1.cpp file" . How do i link a cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

i've only made a simple print function which i define here in **Source1.cpp**

this file name should be **Header1.cpp**

```
 #include "Header1.h"

 void print() {
    cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;
 }
```

Comment: That's not necessarily the reason for the error. It's good style to name header and source the same, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linkage problem.

You've to compile Source1.cpp and to link it.

Comment: I'm just learning about this chapter in school, how do i link these files?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Compilers compile your source code into pieces of programs. You have to link them in order to get a porgram. 
The command to use dependes on the compiler.

Comment: i am using visual studios 2015

Comment: Well I can't help you. Anyway this is a linking issue. The problem is in the way you are compiling.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing std::iostream:

```
 #include "Header1.h"
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void print() {
    cout << "HELLO WORLD" << endl;
 }
```